# sending an email using PHPMailer-5.2 from my gmail account not working on live server

Tags: php, phpmailer

if have seen people asking the same question but Maine is a bit different.

I have a contact me form which I receive all the sender information like name, email, subject, and message and I send that information to my email address from my email address using PHPMailer-5.2.
I submit the form without refreshing the page using js and it works fine on localhost but not on live server.
I don't know why pls I need help?

here is the code

contact form

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    if(name && email && subject && message) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: {
                     user_name:name,
                     user_email:email,
                     user_subject:subject,
                     user_message:message
            },
            success: function (response) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Message sent successfully. I will reply as soon as possible!";;
  
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>    
<form>
    <p>
        <label> Your Name (required)<br />
        <input id="name" required="" type="text" /><br />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label> Your Email (required)<br />
        <input id="email" required="" type="email" /><br />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label> Subject (required)<br />
        <input id="subject" required="" type="text" /><br />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label> Your Message (required)<br />
        <textarea cols="40" id="message" required="" rows="10"></textarea><br />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return chk()">
    </p>
</form>

<p id="status"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

sendmail.php

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer-5.2-stable/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['user_message']))
{
    $name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $email=$_POST['user_email'];
    $subject=$_POST['user_subject'];
    $message=$_POST['user_message'];

    $email1="dagm*****@gmail.com";

    $message1 = "Name : ".$name."<br>"."Email : ".$email."<br>"."Subject : ".$subject."<br>".$message;

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth =true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '465';
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->Username = 'dagmawi****@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '***********';
    $mail->SetFrom($email);
    $mail->Subject = $subjec;
    $mail->Body = $message1;
    $mail->AddAddress($email1);
    
    $mail->Send();
}
?>
```

Comment: I would have though you would need a call to `event.preventDefault();` in `chk()` to stop the form being submitted as well as the Ajax submission

Comment: Look at the logs on your server, that should tell you something

Comment: Two things: upgrade to latest PHPMailer; read the troubleshooting guide that shows you how to diagnose issues like this. Gmail has some oddities that are very well documented. Also base your code on The PHPMailer examples - you have no debug output and no error checking, so you’re not going to be able to even tell it’s failing, let alone see why.

Comment: there is nothing to do with the ajax it works fine the problem is with sendmail.php

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace your `$mail->IsHTML();` to `$mail->IsHTML(true);` and remove `$mail->Body = $message1;` just add `$mail->MsgHTML($message1);` after `$mail->AddAddress($email1);`

Comment: These changes will not do anything.